# How would you Construct a Class object, add click event, and change the color of object from an array of colors(Random -> only if != | | prev.color)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

Good Morning Community!

I have been coding in JavaScript for < 1 year now and I am getting hung up on a small problem.
I am creating a simulation that allows a user to choose between 2 shapes that are colored with an array of colors for each shape. When one is clicked, both recolor with a new pair. I haven't even gotten to the keeping score portion, but I hope by reaching out someone can help guide me in the right direction.

Note: I have been coding, deleting, coding, and mixing things up. I didn't want to change it further because it is closer to what I want currently. S.O.S!

P.S. I realize that it is a bit messy now. I guess that's what happens in the world of code(In the beginning)

Be Gentle HAHA... I went down the rabbit hole

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = "400";
canvas.height = "200";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

const color = ['#f00','#f60','#ff0','#0f0','#0ff','#60f','#a0f']

class Shape{
    constructor(x, y, size, color, key){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.key = key;
    }

    clicked(pX,pY){
    let d = dist(pX,pY, this.x, this.y)
    if (d < this.radius){
        return console.log("True");
    } else {
        return console.log("False");
    }
}

draw(ctx){
    
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.fillStyle = newColor();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        const key = 0;
        ctx.key = key + 1
    }
}

let group = [ ];

function setup( ){
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){ 
    let x = 125 + 150 * i
    let y = 100
    let size = 40
    let key = 1 * i
    let color = newColor();
    let circle = new Shape(x, y, size, color, key);
    circle.draw(ctx);
    group.push(circle);
    
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    console.log("canvas")
})

function newColor(){
        var randomColor = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]
        console.log(randomColor)
        return randomColor
    }

setup( );
```

Comment: Your `newColor` function doesn't make much sense. What is it meant to be doing? At the moment you're just repeatedly assigning a color to `color` (and not properly declaring `color`).

Comment: Create two circles, allow for two colors that are not the same, then change when either circle is clicked. I realize it is a bit redundant now, I just didn't want to spend hours on this again; being it somewhat of an easier problem. I just can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: ```const color = ['#f00','#f60','#ff0','#0f0','#0ff','#60f','#a0f']                                   
      function newColor(){                                                                                              
 var randomColor = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color[0].length)]                  return randomColor
    } ```
Here is what I did to at least randomize it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I took a step back and solved the initial issue.
This works so far, If anyone has any advice on how to make the "circle" the object unless it already is. I couldn't console.log() this. I may be missing just one thing.

```
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    
    canvas.width = "800";
    canvas.height = "600";
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    
    let group = []
    
    function Shape(x, y, size, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.n = function (){
             return this.x, this.y, this.size, this.color
        };
        
    }
    
    function selectColor(color){
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#'
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           color += letters[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16))];
           return color
    }
    
    function draw(x, y, size, color){
        
        let circle = new Object();
        new Shape(x, y, size, color);
        for(var i =  0; i < 2; i++){
            let x = canvas.height/2 + 200 * i;
            let y = canvas.width / 2.5;
            let size = 40;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            let color = selectColor();
            ctx.fillStyle = selectColor();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            group.push(circle);
            // console.log(x, y, size, color)
        }
        return circle, x, y, size, color
    }
    
    draw();
```